# Cant apply CSS style

Tags: php, html, css

Ive been trying to increase the font size for the TH tag via the css style sheet:

```
th {
    color:#D5DDE5;
    background:#1b1e24;
    border-bottom:4px solid #9ea7af;
    border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
    font-size:23px;
    font-weight: 100;
    padding:24px;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

for the following code:

```
<?php
include ('connect-mysql.php');

$sqlget="SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY score desc LIMIT 10";
$sqldata= mysqli_query($conn, $sqlget);

echo "<table width='1500'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Position</th>";
echo "<th>First Name</th>";
echo "<th>Last Name</th>";
echo "<th>Score</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$counter = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td width='5%'>";
    echo "<b>".$counter."</b>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<div style='font-size:40px'>";
    echo "<b>".$row['firstName']."</b>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<div style='font-size:40px'>";
    echo "<b>".$row['lastName']."</b>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</td><td width='20%'>";
    echo "<b>".$row['score']."</b>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    $counter++;
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

As you can see i have been using inline css styles as the external style sheet seems to have jammed, i would like to increase the font size of the TH tags but there is no response when changing 'font-size:23px'

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: Inspect the element in Chrome and click on the 'computed' tab to see which property is responsible for setting the font-size on that element.

Comment: don't use `!important` unless it's the only way to do it, which is probably not the case here. The future you will be thankful. Actually it might be another `!important` tag messing with this here.

Comment: Trying adding an ID or class to the tag to increase CSS specificity https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Make it like this, and you're done...

```
echo "<table width='1500'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th style="font-size:23px;">Position</th>";
echo "<th style="font-size:23px;">First Name</th>";
echo "<th style="font-size:23px;">Last Name</th>";
echo "<th style="font-size:23px;">Score</th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

add inline css to th tags...

Comment: If OP wanted to style another TH like this, then he/she would have to write all this CSS code over. It's better to keep the CSS separate from HTML.

Comment: This is not a good solution imo. Also, at least escape the characters.

Comment: Either escape the double-quotes or use single quotes `echo '<th style="font-size:23px;">Position</th>';` etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change font-size in the browser development panel.

It will show you if there are some other css instructions that overwrites yours (or any other reason).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this I managed to get it to work using kunals help.

```
echo "<th style='font-size:2.0em'>Position</th>";
```

using "" instead of ''inside the th tag causes php errors for me.
using px caused formatting issues so i used em

I am still wondering why my CSS style sheet isnt working :/

Comment: you would need to escape the `"` with `\ ` -> `\"` within the php scripts string. Otherwise PHP will think you end the string with the next `"` which you don't want to.

Comment: `echo "<th style=\"font-size:2.0em\">Position</th>";`